# Store common elements of 2 lists as 0 and 1s

Tags: python, list

I want to write a function subsetOf() to find the common elements of two lists and store any common elements in a separate list as a 1 and any non-common elements as a 0. For example:

```
L=[2,17,12,5,66,20,7]
M =[2,12,66]
```

The function should return :

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use `list comprehensions`.

```
your_list = [1 if x in M else 0 for x in L]
print(your_list)
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

In function form:

```
def subsetOf(L,M):
    return [1 if x in M else 0 for x in L]

print(subsetOf(L,M))
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (for speed):

```
L = [2, 17, 12, 5, 66, 20, 7]
M = [2, 12, 66]
comm = [1 if x in set(M) else 0 for x in L]
print(comm)
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```